# Porting an iPhone app on iPad to make a universal app

Tags: ipad, uiactionsheet

i have a similar question about UIActionSheet on iPad, actionnaly i have an iPhone app that i want to port on iPad, for the xib there is no problem the auto-Resizing is doing it very well, but for the UIActionSheet and the alertViews that i'm using to call UIDatePickers i have troubles, the first problem is the alertView: it displays only in portrait mode it doesn't rotate with the view (perhaps i could replace it with PopOverController?) the second problem is the UIActionSheet containing the UIDatePicker, when i'm on the iPad simulator it shows me a little empty rectangle inspite the UIDatePicker What should i do to port my UIActionSheet on iPad? i'm waiting for your help Thank you very much

Comment: Hello, StackOverflow contains millions of questions that are not shown in any particular order. If you are referring to a specific question, you'd better link to it.

Answer (score 0):

In both cases it seems like a UIPopOverController seem appropriate.  The main difference is that the UIPopOverController expects a viewController to control it.  Beyond that, it's implementation is similar to both an actionSheet and an alertView.